# What is typical sink rate of sinking air, and the typical rate of climb for a glider with a sustainer engine?

Tags: aerodynamics

What is the typical rate of climb for a glider with a sustainer engine with only lift provided by the engine (no thermal lift, ridge lift, etc.)

I understand a self launching glider is almost like a modern ultralight with motors in the 80 Hp range. That probably puts the rate of climb at 400-600ft/min for a weight of 1,200lbs.

In Canada, the light aircraft specifications for homebuilt type aircraft specify a minimum rate of climb of 300 ft/min, which is at the low end of what many modern  homebuilts are capable of, at least those with around 80 Hp engines.

I understand gliders with sustainer engines are meant to "sustain altitude" and cannot self launch. I'm told they are typical about 20 hp.

Yet, what happens if you are gliding over a flat farming region just prior to sundown, thermal lift is long gone and you are "in sink", i.e. in a sinking air region with 100 ft/min sink, and your glider can only climb at 50 ft/min.  This means you're going down at 50 ft/min, no matter what. Having said that, I understand sink typically stops several hundred feet off the ground, which means you won't be slammed into the ground by the sink, but it also means you would have to fly below 1,000ft obstacle clearance and less than 1,000 ft above ground level ( AGL)

I'm sure there is a typical sink rate of descending air over fields and a typical rate of climb even for sustainers.  Just wondering what those two values are.

I would imagine that the typical rate of climb of sustainers is engineered to be above a typical rate of descending air in sink.

Comment: There's no way to give you a hard answer. Sink over 500 fpm is unusual unless you are right next to a strong thermal (it's vertical circulation in the end).  Flying around at dinner time, most of the thermal activity has petered out, and so has most of the convection-related sink.  I would be surprised to hit sink more than a couple hundred fpm at most, and that may be more due to subsidence (and therefore more widespread) than convective activity.

Comment: Any  idea on a typical rate of climb for a glider with a sustainer engine? With 20 Hp, I'm estimating it would be only 50 to 100 ft/min.

Comment: 20 HP will make about 80-100 lbs of thrust. A single seat motor glider with just moderate performance, say 30:1, weighing 600lbs all up, will need 20lbs for level flight with the rest available for climb, say 70 lbs or about 17 thrust HP lifting 600 lbs.   It should do better than that.

Comment: This question seems poorly framed (what does "typical" mean, when up and down drafts can vary widely, depending on terrain, atmospheric conditions, etc. and when there are a variety of aircraft that might be considered?), and not very practical either, since a pilot will not intentionally stay in sinking air in a glider for any longer than absolutely necessary.